# Area enclosed by two polar graphs $r=\sin\theta$ and $r=\cos2\theta$

Tags: polar-coordinates

I need to find the area enclosed by two polar graphs $r=\sin\theta$ and $r=\cos2\theta$ within the positive quadrant. However I am unsure which section of the curves i am to use to find the enclosed area as several areas could be taken as the correct on in my opinion. Which area should I find? Also is this a common issue to have with polar graphs that I'm just not used to?

I also have found that the graph cross at the origin and $(0.5,\frac{1\pi}{6})$

Comment: The graphs also are tangent at $(1,\frac12\pi).$ If I had to guess I would guess the region bounded by the two arcs with endpoints at the origin and at $(\frac12,\frac16\pi)$ is desired. But it's a question that can come up when there are multiple curves involved, not only when the equation is polar.

Comment: It can depend on exactly how the problem was phrased. If it asked for the area *between* the two graphs, then I would guess it means where $$\cos 2\theta \le r \le \sin\theta$$ That is, the wedge inside the circle, but outside the two petals. But no matter what, the the problem is unclear.